# Unable to run on https in nodejs server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ssl

I have created following certificate and key(self-signed). When I run the app, the browser loads with `Not secure` and `https` is striked off. It should run on https right when the key and cert is available?

Code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var request = require('request');
var rp = require('request-promise');

var port = process.env.PORT || 5026;
app.set('port', (port));
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public_html'));


var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./server.key', 'utf8'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./server.crt', 'utf8')
};

http.createServer(app).listen(8080);
https.createServer(options, app).listen(8443);
```

There's no error in console though. I have never worked with ssl before. What am I missing here?

**Update:** **Added CA Certificate and private key**

But now I get this **error:**

```
Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
    at Error (native)
    at Object.createSecureContext (_tls_common.js:65:17)
    at Server (_tls_wrap.js:758:25)
```

I am using windows OS. But why this error? How should I fix this?

Comment: Browsers only consider communication secure if the certificate is signed (directly or indirectly) by one of the root certificates it recognises. A self-signed cert is not, so it complains. Clicking on the lock should give you more information about it. Try the same with a recognised signed cert (there are many cheap and even free certs that are recognised).

Comment: @jcaron Could you please provide any link where I can get some cheap ca certs? tx